# How to reduce Independent set to SAT?

Tags: time-complexity, reductions

My professor gave the reduction of Independent Set (IS) $\leq_p$ SAT where SAT is the set of all satisfiable propositional formulas in conjunctive normal form, and IS the set of all pairs (G,k) where G is an undirected graph with an independent set of size k, given as as an exercise and I'm a little confused as to what I am supposed to do to get this reduction.

I know that we have to define a function $f$ that'll map IS to SAT but I'm not entirely sure on how to approach this question.

Tips on intuition or how to approach this question are greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about using the proof of [Cook-Levin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook–Levin_theorem)?

Comment: In addition, it seems the title should be "reduce IS to SAT".

Comment: Right thanks! Ill look into the Cook-Levin Theorem

Comment: Cook-Levin solves the problem but that's like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. It's almost certainly not what your professor had in mind.